# Nominatim 3.4.1 installation fails on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, nominatim, apache

I am trying to install Nominatim 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 using the instructions [here](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/appendix/Install-on-Ubuntu-18/). When it is time to setup the Apache Web Server I get the following error after entering this command in the terminal.

```
gerry@gerry:/etc/apache2$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
gerry@gerry:/etc/apache2$
```

I have a file here /etc/apache2/conf-available/nominatim.conf  that contains this text but I am unsure if this is correct.

```
<< EOFAPACHECONF
<Directory "$USERHOME/Nominatim/build/website">
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AddType text/html   .php
DirectoryIndex search.php
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /nominatim $USERHOME/Nominatim/build/website
EOFAPACHECONF
```

Why can't I restart apache2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the top and bottom lines of your nominatim.conf (<< EOFAPACHECONF) and replace $USERHOME with the path to the home directory of your user nominatim. That should solve the problem of restarting apache.